# Run application in cwd on remote host from within eshell

Tags: tramp, eshell

I often use Eshell to connect to remote systems.  On those remote systems I sometimes want to run scripts in the current working directory.  In a regular terminal I'd type this:

```
./my-script.sh
```

Unfortunately, inside of Eshell this won't work:

```
~ $ cd /remote1:~
/ssh:remote1:/home/rekado $ ./my-script.sh 
env: /ssh:remote1:/home/rekado/my-script.sh: No such file or directory
/ssh:remote1:/home/rekado $
```

It only works if I provide the complete TRAMP path to the script:

```
/ssh:remote1:/home/rekado $ /ssh:remote1:/home/rekado/my-script.sh 
It works!
/ssh:remote1:/home/rekado $
```

Is there a way to convince Eshell to expand `.` automatically such that the simpler invocation just works?

As a workaround I currently use a function bound to `C-c .` that inserts the current full path on the command line.  I'd much prefer to have `.` just behave as expected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks like a bug in `eshell`, you should report it.

I *think* you can fix it by

```
(defadvice eshell-gather-process-output (before absolute-cmd (command args) act)
  (setq command (file-truename command)))
```

Bottom-line, the problem is that tramp ends up constructing a remote command line of the form (I'm removing some escaping to make it clearer):

```
cd /home/rekado && exec env PS1='/ssh:remote1:/home/rekado $' /ssh:remote1:/home/rekado/my-script.sh
```

Which is why you end up with that "mysterious" message about `env`

What it needs to generate instead (and that's what's achieved by the command above) is something like

```
cd /home/rekado && exec env PS1='/ssh:remote1:/home/rekado $' /home/rekado/my-script.sh
```

I do believe the bug is on the eshell side though, since tramp has no way of knowing that "/ssh:remote1:..." is not a valid remote command (although if it was, we'd probably have a lot more problems with multi-hop tramp... but anyways). And eshell indeed does the sane thing when the command is explicitly a tramp path.

Comment: Works smoothly. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: It is a bug indeed and has been fixed upstream already.

Comment: @rekado, Which version of emacs is it fixed in?

Comment: I believe it was fixed with this commit: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?id=882370eaa4f7ad6a88396dfdc64f896c727f87f4

Comment: I encountered this bug and had to apply the above fix (which corrects the problem --- thank you for that). I am running emacs 24.5.1 installed via homebrew on a mac. The upstream fix does not correct the problem for me.